# Como fazer um filtro duplo em um dataframe com formato longo

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

Tenho um `DF` em formato longo com dados de vários países. Gostaria de fazer um filtro para buscar o último valor disponível da variável `total_tests` de cada país, os que não possuem dado estão representados por um `NA`. Este dado está disponível em datas diferentes para cada país, o que me fez ter problemas ao utilizar um `filter(date == max(date))` ou `filter(!is.na(total_tests))`.

Código:

```
library(tidycovid19) # Pacote do GitHub - https://github.com/joachim-gassen/tidycovid19
library(tidyverse)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

updates %>%
    filter(date == max(date), !is.na(total_tests))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira:

1. Eliminaria todas as linhas com `NA` em `total_tests`
2. Converteria `date` para data, pois assim é possível estabelecer uma relação de ordem nessa coluna
3. Ordenaria o data frame por `country` e por `date`, de modo a ter certeza de que todas as observações de cada país estão juntas e em ordem crescente por `date`
4. Agruparia por país
5. Aplicaria a função `tail` com argumento 1, para manter apenas a última linha de cada bloco de observações de cada país

O código final ficou assim:

```
library(tidycovid19)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

updates %>%
  filter(!is.na(total_tests)) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  arrange(country, date) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  do(tail(., 1))
# A tibble: 83 x 35
# Groups:   country [83]
   iso3c country date       confirmed deaths recovered ecdc_cases ecdc_deaths
   <chr> <chr>   <date>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 ARG   Argent… 2020-06-01     17415    556      5521      16838         539
 2 AUS   Austra… 2020-05-31      7202    103      6618       7185         103
 3 AUT   Austria 2020-06-01     16733    668     15596      16642         668
 4 BHR   Bahrain 2020-06-01     11871     19      7070      11398          19
 5 BGD   Bangla… 2020-05-31     47153    650      9781      44608         610
 6 BLR   Belarus 2020-06-01     43403    240     18776      42556         235
 7 BEL   Belgium 2020-05-30     58186   9453     15769      58061        9443
 8 BOL   Bolivia 2020-05-31      9982    313       968       9592         310
 9 BRA   Brazil  2020-05-29    465166  27878    189476     438238       26754
10 BGR   Bulgar… 2020-06-01      2519    140      1090       2513         140
# … with 73 more rows, and 27 more variables: total_tests <dbl>,
#   tests_units <chr>, soc_dist <dbl>, mov_rest <dbl>, pub_health <dbl>,
#   gov_soc_econ <dbl>, lockdown <dbl>, apple_mtr_driving <dbl>,
#   apple_mtr_walking <dbl>, apple_mtr_transit <dbl>,
#   gcmr_retail_recreation <dbl>, gcmr_grocery_pharmacy <dbl>, gcmr_parks <dbl>,
#   gcmr_transit_stations <dbl>, gcmr_workplaces <dbl>, gcmr_residential <dbl>,
#   gtrends_score <dbl>, gtrends_country_score <int>, region <chr>,
#   income <chr>, population <dbl>, land_area_skm <dbl>, pop_density <dbl>,
#   pop_largest_city <dbl>, life_expectancy <dbl>, gdp_capita <dbl>,
#   timestamp <dttm>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado!